# If $(x - \frac {1}{x})^2 = 2$ and $x > 0$ what is $x^4 - \frac{1}{x^4}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $(x - \frac {1}{x})^2 = 2$ and $x > 0$ what is $x^4 - \frac{1}{x^4}$?

I tried factorising the $x^4 - \frac{1}{x^4}$ expression and I got $(x^2 - \frac {1}{x^2})(x - \frac {1}{x})(x + \frac {1}{x})$ but I'm not sure what to do from here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$$x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}=4,$$ which gives
$$x^2=2+\sqrt3$$ or
$$x^2=2-\sqrt3.$$
Thus, $$x^4-\frac{1}{x^4}=4\left(x^2-\frac{1}{ x^2}\right)=8\sqrt3$$ or
$$x^4-\frac{1}{x^4}=-8\sqrt3.$$

Comment: I got $$x^2_{1,2}=2\pm\sqrt{3}$$

Answer (score 1):

We use $(a+b)^2=(a-b)^2+4ab$ where $ab=1$

If $(x-\frac 1x)^2=2$ then $(x+\frac 1x)^2=2+4=6$

Then $$\left(x^2-\frac 1{x^2}\right)^2=(x-\frac 1x)^2(x+\frac 1x)^2=2\times 6=12$$

Then using the basic formula again 
$$\left(x^2+\frac 1{x^2}\right)^2=12+4=16$$ and $$\left(x^4-\frac 1{x^4}\right)^2=\left(x^2+\frac 1{x^2}\right)^2\left(x^2-\frac 1{x^2}\right)^2=16\times 12$$

whence $$x^4-\frac 1{x^4}=\pm 8\sqrt 3$$ The sign is positive if $|x|\gt 1$. Switching $x$ and $\frac 1x$ changes the sign of the result without changing any of the intermediate calculations.

Comment: A very neat approach.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x^4-\dfrac{1}{x^4}=a$, then in **pari/gp**:

```
? polresultant((x^2-1)^2-2*x^2,x^8-1-a*x^4,x)
%1 = a^4 - 384*a^2 + 36864
? factor(%)
%2 =
[a^2 - 192 2]
```

and $a=\sqrt{192}=8\sqrt{3}$

Answer (score 0):

We have $x^4-1/x^4=(x^2+1/x^2)(x^2-1/x^2)$

Now $x^2+1/x^2=(x-1/x)^2+2=4$

Let $x^2-1/x^2=2c$

$\implies x^2=2+c$

and $1/x^2=2-c$

$\implies(2+c)(2-c)=1\implies c^2=3,c=?$

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

You must have gotten:
$$x^4 - \frac{1}{x^4}=\left(x^2\color{red}+\frac1{x^2}\right)\left(x^2-\frac1{x^2}\right)=\color{red}4\cdot (\color{blue}{\pm2\sqrt{3}})=\pm8\sqrt{3},$$
because:
$$\left(x-\frac1x\right)^2=2 \Rightarrow x^2+\frac1{x^2}-2=2\Rightarrow x^2+\frac1{x^2}=\color{red}4 \Rightarrow \\
(x^2)^2-4x^2+1=0 \Rightarrow x^2=2\pm \sqrt{3} \ ;\\
x^2+\frac1{x^2}=4\Rightarrow x^2-\frac1{x^2}=2x^2-4=\color{blue}{\pm 2\sqrt{3}}.$$

Answer (score 0):

$(x - \frac {1}{x})^2 = 2\implies x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}-2=2\implies x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}=4$

Again $(x + \frac {1}{x})^2=(x - \frac {1}{x})^2+4x\cdot\frac{1}{x}=2+4=6\implies x + \frac {1}{x}=\sqrt6\qquad \text{as}\quad x > 0$

$(x - \frac {1}{x})^2=2\implies x - \frac {1}{x}=\sqrt2 \qquad \text{as}\quad x > 0$

Now $x^4 - \frac{1}{x^4}=(x^2 - \frac{1}{x^2})(x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2})=(x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2})(x - \frac{1}{x})(x + \frac{1}{x})=4\cdot(\sqrt2) \cdot(\sqrt6)=8\sqrt3 $.

Answer (score -1):

Note that by expanding we have $2 = \left(x - \frac{1}{x} \right)^2 = x^2 - 2\frac{x}{x} + \frac{1}{x^2} = x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2} - 2$. So we have $x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2} = 4$, and squaring this again gives $x^4 + 2 + \frac{1}{x^4}=16$. So our answer is $14$.

Comment: OP asked $x^4 - 1/x^4$ rather than  $x^4 + 1/x^4$.